# MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm busy trying to get the MapView included in my Android project. I'm following the MapView tutorial on the Android developer website but I'm getting an error:

```
'MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type'
```

I tried pressing Ctrl+Shift+O to auto import all classes but it's not helping. When I try to include the Maps libary manually it gives this error:

```
'The import com.google.android cannot be resolved'
```

I have added the following line (see below) to the Manifest and my target is API 7 (Platform: 2.1).

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have your projects build target set to Google API's?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've used the Android SDK Manager to get all packages. I've installed all the avaiable packages and after all the Google API's build target is still not in the list? I have all Android packages (1.5 till 4.0) though.

Comment: You are using eclipse, correct? Try going to Window>Android SDK and ADK Manager>Installed Packages, then make sure they are up to date.

Comment: I've installed all packages and they are all up to date, but the Google API's is still not turning up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google API is a third party SDK. Choose third party in packages manager.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I've opened the SDK manager again, but I can't see any third party SDK's? See this screenshot: http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/1340/sdk.png

Comment: Try to select Sort by: Repository. If You still cant see it: Tools->Manage Ad-on Sites and add https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

Comment: Great thanks, I've got the Google Api's now in my packages list!! Had to add a new ad-on.

Answer (score 9):

You need to reference correct library at compile time. But what you describe is asking Android to use this specific library at runtime.

You need to right click your Eclipse project, Properties -> Android. In Project Build Target select any target with vendor Google Inc..